# Where is the data stored in Corda Database?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I understand that the default DB is H2 that every node uses locally. I'm trying to understand where is the actual transaction data (the payload) stored. Also, I'm wondering what would happen if I change the data in the database directly on a node. What would happen if I query the other node?

```
PartyA = Data1
PartyB = Data1
PartyC = Data1
```

Now I corrupt PartyB's version in it's database to Data2:
Now it becomes:

```
PartyA = Data1
PartyB = Data2
PartyC = Data1
```

What would I see if I query PartyB? 
What would I see if I query PartyC?

Answer (score 0):

Each transaction is stored as a blob in the node's database in the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table. Various pieces of information are also extracted and stored in other tables (e.g. the states are stored individually in the `VAULT_STATES` table).

What happens when you corrupt the data depends on which table you corrupt. If you corrupt data on `PartyB`, `PartyC` will be completely unaffected. `PartyB` may see the wrong on-ledger data, or may propose invalid transactions, or other side effects. It depends on what data is corrupted and how.